# Scheduling Airflow Dag Runs to have exact times rather than cron

Tags: cron, airflow

I have a two DAGs.

DAG A: picks up a zip file from a folder and unzips it at 8am.

it always extracts 5 csv files.

DAG B: parses a csv file.

I want DAG B to execute exactly 10 min after DAG A
And I want DAG B to only execute 5 times, and for those 5 dag runs to execute 10 minutes after each other.

How can I get airflow to do this?

Here is an example future dates:

```
- DAG A tommorrow 8:00AM 
- DAG B tommorrow 8:10AM
- DAG B tommorrow 8:20AM
- DAG B tommorrow 8:30AM
- DAG B tommorrow 8:40AM
- DAG B tommorrow 8:50AM
*  done no more dag run until the next day
```

Comment: Why not use cron for running dags every 10 minutes? Something like this "10/10 8 * * *" would run at 8:10. 8:20 .... 8:50?

Comment: @Sharif - because, I dont want it to also run at 9:10, 9:20, 9:30 , etc

Comment: "10/10 8 * * *" would run every 10 minutes, starting at 10 minutes past the hour, between 08:00 AM and 08:59 AM, it will not run at 9:10 etc .
First parameter 10/10 is minutes - every 10 minutes 
second parameter 8 is hour

Comment: @Sharif magic! I think that is it!

Comment: Are the names of the CSV files always the same?

Comment: Why do you have 2 DAGs for this instead of doing everything in one? It looks like a single workflow.

Comment: Are the exact times important or is it enough to have 10 min delays between tasks?

Comment: @SergiyKolesnikov - not really, In this case it is important that it only runs 5 times, and that they have at least 10 min to finish, before starting the next one, also, the sooner it finishes all 5, the better